# Why is that noexcept specifier doesn't work in complete class context but default argument and function body does

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, noexcept, exception-specification

I'm learning C++ using the books listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, I read about complete-class context and came to know that it includes function-body, default argument, noexcept-specifier etc. Now, to further clear my understanding of the topic, I wrote the following program where `#1` and `#2` works but `#3` fails. I don't know why `#3` fails because I read that all the three(function body, default argument and noexcept specifier) are included in the complete-class context.

```
struct A {
   constexpr static bool func() 
   { 
       return true; 
   }
   //--------------vvvvvv------->works as expected   #1
   void f(bool V1 = func())
   { 
      bool V2 = func(); //works as expected          #2
   }
   //-----------------vvvvvv---->DOESN'T WORK?       #3
   void g()  noexcept(func()) 
   {
      ;
   }

};
```

> A complete-class context of a class is a
>
> - function body
> - default argument
> - noexcept specifier

As you can see the third point says "noexcept specifier" so i expected `#3` to works as well but it doesn't.

So **my question is** why `#3` doesn't work unlike `#1` and `#2`? [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/njsqcTqhY)

GCC gives the error with `#3`:

```
 error: 'static constexpr bool A::func()' called in a constant expression before its definition is complete
   20 |    void g()  noexcept(func())
```

Clang gives:

```
error: noexcept specifier argument is not a constant expression
   void g()  noexcept(func()) 
                      ^~~~~~
<source>:20:23: note: undefined function 'func' cannot be used in a constant expression
<source>:10:26: note: declared here
   constexpr static bool func()
```

MSVC gives:

```
 error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(20): note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'
<source>(20): note: see usage of 'A::func'
```

Comment: There's a lot of books on that list you are reading!  From what particular book on that list did you read about *complete-class context*, and what was the page number?

Answer (score 3):

The program is **well-formed** and *all the three compilers are wrong in rejecting the code* as `noexcept-specifier` is included in complete-class context as quoted in the question.

Here are the respective bug reports:

[GCC rejects use of static constexpr member function in noexcept complete-class context](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107186)

[Clang rejects use of static constexpr member function in noexcept complete-class context](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58245)

[MSVC rejects use of static constexpr member function in noexcept complete-class context](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-use-of-static-constexpr-mem/10166701?)

Comment: Microsoft has decided it's not a bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/static-constexpr-method-is-not-constant-/10009811

Comment: @Spencer No, actually [they admitted that it is indeed a bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-use-of-static-constexpr-mem/10166701#TPIN-N10167796-N10169206). First they were saying that it is not a bug but then I said that according to the current wording it is a bug to which they agree. See the complete [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-use-of-static-constexpr-mem/10166701#TPIN-N10167796-N10169206).

Comment: That's a **highly** qualified admission, followed by a long discussion about why the "bug" is unlikely to ever be addressed.   More likely the Standard will change to follow [this defect report from 2013](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1626) and remove the capability.

Comment: @Spencer *"bug is unlikely to ever be addressed."* I'm not so sure about that because I came to know that the current wording(about including noexcept specifier in complete-class context) is completely intentional. This mean that just like in OP's example we're able to use `func()` as default argument at `#1` and also at initializer at `#2`, we should be able to use `func()` inside the noexcept-specifier as it is also a complete-class context.

Comment: The wording is from C++11, before `noexcept` affected a function's type.  Per Jonathan Emmet @ Microsoft: _"given that no compiler I’ve tried has implemented this 10 year old feature I am unsure how much (if at all) the issue of complete-class-context noexcept-specifiers informed the design of these later features."_